# why while loop doesn't work inside a another loop (for in range)

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop, python-3.7

I want to run a function (def) 100 times using `while` (with numbers from 0 - 1000000)

But the `while` doesn't break the loop when needed.
How can I fix it?

```py
count = 2  #I start from 2 on purpose
limit = 101

def is_prime(i):
    global count
    count+=1
    #there is more to the function is_prime but it isn't relevant 
    #i made a function with input to show a example

while (count < limit):
    for i in range(1000000):
        is_prime(i)
        print ("count = ", count)
```

I expect it to stop when it gets to `count` = 100

Comment: Now that you changed it, the issue cannot be reproduced. The code does not hang.

Comment: The inner ``for`` loop does not care about the exit strategy of the outer while loop, thus it will go on until it reaches the end ( ``range(1000000)`` in your case ) and **then** then ``while`` loop exits.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one - in order to interact with the global variable from the inside of subroutine - you need to indicate it's global. Otherwise it's just local function variable with the same name, as the existing global variable

```py
count = 2  #I start from 2 on purpose
limit = 101

def is_prime(i):
    global count
    count+=1
    #there is more to the function is_prime but it isn't relevant 
    #i made a function with input to show a example

while (count < limit):
    for i in range(1000000):
        is_prime(i)
        print ("count = ", count)
print(count)
```

Comment: sorry, my mistake I already tried it and I forgot to put it in the code. unfortunately, it didn't work...

Comment: but it limits while loop, why it doesn't work from your perspective ? I.e. what would you like to have differently in terms of outcome ?

Comment: it doesn't work from my perspective because the loop didn't "break" (stop) after the while conditional is False. I don't get any errors it just continue forever

Comment: It did, it just first executes inner for - and once for is done, re-evaluates condition in while